# ImportError: cannot import name 'Users' from 'user'

Tags: python, tkinter, import

Good people, for you to understand, I'm doing in 2 files my work. But when I'm in the Y file and import the X, it runs, it has the normal screen manipulation. Now when I'm in X importing Y, having already imported into Y the X, it returns me this error. In short, I get on the system soon, but when I want to log out (go back to the login window) it will not let me.

I did not try anything, because I do not know what to do.

```
from app import loginUser

class Users:

   def __init__(self,window):      
      # Criando o sistema
      self.wind = window
      self.wind.title("System F2T")
```

---

```
 from user import Users

 class loginUser:
 #Metodo de inicio ao sistema de login
   def __init__(self, window, master=None):   
      # Criando o sistema de login
       self.wind = window
       self.wind.title("System F2T")
```

I hope you can help me, because I stopped at this. I put a piece of code so to understand that I'm making an interaction from one to the other

Comment: what are the name of both files ?

Comment: Try ```from folder.file import classname```

Comment: Is that a circular import, where both files import the other?

Comment: Yes! exactly, they both care.

Comment: I did not understand this folder.file, in my error / ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import only module/file you didn't need to import class. Where ever you want to use `loginuser` class use it using `app.loginUser()` and `user.Users()` for `Users` class. Below code works fine for me:

```
import app
class Users:
   def __init__(self,window):      
      return app.loginUser()
```

---

```
import user
class loginUser:
   def __init__(self, window, master=None):  
       return user.Users()
```

Comment: I did as you put it and gave this following error.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Users'

Comment: @felipi it is working fine in my system. Can you share your code and sytem information?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear, you say "it returns me this error" but then do not provide the error you are getting. From what I can gather you should be getting the error : `ImportError: cannot import name 'loginUser' from 'app' (C:\User\ProjectName\app.py)`

This error is occurring because you are trying to import `Users` from `user.py` into `app.py`, and also trying to import `loginUser` from `app.py` into `users.py`. This is a import loop and causes the error.

> In short, `user.py` cannot rely upon code from `app.py` if `app.py`
>   also relies upon `user.py` itself.

One way to fix this error, is to import loginUser into the specific functions that it is needed within User (Or Vice Versa, depending on what your two classes need to do).

e.g. - If a Users object needs to create a new loginUser in a function called `createUser()`, the two files would look like the following

```
# app.py

from user import Users

class loginUser:
 #Metodo de inicio ao sistema de login
   def __init__(self, window, master=None):   
      # Criando o sistema de login
       self.wind = window
       self.wind.title("System F2T")
```

```
# user.py

class Users:

   def __init__(self,window):      
      # Criando o sistema
      self.wind = window
      self.wind.title("System F2T")

   def createUser(self):
      from app import loginUser
      newUser = loginUser(self.wind)
      return newUser
```